# Unordered sets as columns / Python's frozenset object

Tags: python, sas

I am trying to replicate the following pattern (shown in Python) in SAS:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('abc'), 'b': list('cba')})
>>> df
   a  b
0  a  c
1  b  b
2  c  a
>>> df['key'] = [frozenset([x, y]) for x, y in df[['a', 'b']].values]
>>> df
   a  b     key
0  a  c  (a, c)
1  b  b     (b)
2  c  a  (a, c)
>>> df.drop_duplicates('key')
   a  b     key
0  a  c  (a, c)
1  b  b     (b)
```

Effectively, I have two columns, `a` and `b`. This table was produced via a self-join, and `a` and `b` represent the same canonical column. I need to drop duplicates on the combined/concatenated `a` and `b` columns **without preserving the ordering of the values within those columns**. I can do this very easily in Python, using the `frozenset` unordered set collection - see above.

I thought concatenating the columns then sorting might work, but in reality my columns are much more complex than single-letter cells, and the comment from [this](https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/Rearranging-a-Character-Strings-Into-alphabetical-order/td-p/394722) article

> Hmm.  "Tim Mott" and "Tom Mitt" will not match in name form, but will match in sorted anagram form. That could be interesting.

Made it clear that's not what I want to be doing.

Any tips on how to replicate this in SAS?

Edit: Ultimately, this is the view I'm trying to create, basically counting records by that unordered key:

```py
>>> df.groupby('key').size()
key
(a, c)    2
(b)       1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking at two variables it is pretty simple.  Just combine them with the smaller value first.

```
data have ;
  input (var1-var2) ($);
cards;
a  c
b  b
c  a
;

proc sql ;
create table want as
select
  case when var1=var2 then var1
       when var1<var2 then catx(',',var1,var2)
       else catx(',',var2,var1)
  end as key
  , count(*) as size
from have
group by 1
;
quit;
```

Result:

```
Obs    key    size

 1     a,c      2
 2     b        1
```